# How to run code from RAM on ARM architecture

Tags: arm

I am programming an ARM Cortex-R4 and I have a few binary files that I'd like to execute them from TCRAM, just to see if the increase in performance is good enough.

I know I'd have to write a function to copy the binaries to the RAM (which can be accomplished with the linker script, and knowing the size of the binaries). But how would they run?

Imagine this: The first binary has func1(), func2(), func3() and func4(). I'd copy the entire module to TCRAM and how would I call a function there? I'd have to use a function pointer to that specific function? And what if func4(), calls func2() and func3()? If I'm not mistaken they'd point to the piece of code located in the flash. Does that mean I'd have to re write those funcs? Use entirely function pointers? I've been told that just the linker script is enough to do all of this and I needn't worry about anything, but I still don't understand how it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Copy them as you suggest, compile with `pc relative`.
2. Use a linker file with a different load/run address.

A simple copy will only work if the routines do not use any **absolute addresses**.  It maybe fine if they do use the **absolute address** as I guess you are going to leave a copy in standard RAM.  However, this may not get the full benefit of the `TCM`.

With a linker script, you can specify a different `LOAD` and `RUN` locations.

```
sections {
 .text { *(.text); } >FLASH
 .tcm {
       *(.tcm);
  } >TCM_MEM AT>FLASH
  .data { *(.data); } > RAM
  .bss : NOLOAD { *(.bss); } > RAM
}
```

Note especially `AT>FLASH`.

See also: [gnu linker map file...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453996/gnu-linker-map-file-giving-unexpected-load-addresses) and many more on *stackoverflow*. The [Gnu Ld manual](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Output-Section-LMA.html) has information on `LMA` sections (**LOAD** address).  Your `LMA` would be *flash*, but the `VMA` (**RUN** address) would be **TCM**.  The manual link above also shows how to copy.  The `RAM`, `FLASH`, and `TCM_MEM` are defined with ld [MEMORY](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/MEMORY.html) information, depending on the addresses are for your board.  All of this will be documented in a `MAP` file.  Be sure to generate a `MAP` file and examine the addresses to double check your `ld` script.

The 2nd case also requires a copy (at start-up or at least before the first `TCM` function use).  However, the compiler can use **absolute addresses** and they will be in the `TCM` memory.  Also any function within the main `DRAM` can call the `TCM` function directly.  With the first case, you must use function pointers to call the `TCM` code.  If you wish **global** variables to be placed in this memory, you can use attributes to put them in different sections and use *gnu ld* to place them appropriately.  I think there is `ITCM` and `DTCM`?  So maybe this doesn't apply for you, or you need two sections.

The linker script is more generic and will work best if you put complicated functionality in the `TCM`.  Just using `-fpic`, etc and copying may get things working quickly, especially if you only have a single `pure` function.

Answer (score 11):

On GCC: Just put the function in the .data section:

```
__attribute__( ( section(".data") ) )
```

It will be copied over with the rest of your initialzed variables by the startup code (no need to mess with the linker scipt).  You may also need a "long_call" option as well if the function ends up "far away" from the rest of the code after being placed into RAM.

```
__attribute__( ( long_call, section(".data") ) )
```

Example:

```
__attribute__( ( long_call, section(".data") ) ) void ram_foobar (void) { ... }
```

You may get an compiler warning that can be safely ignored:

```
Warning: ignoring changed section attributes for .data
```

Comment: This is useful, but I don't think it will put the function in the TCRAM as the OP requested.  This will put the function in ram in a fairly easy way, but it will not be very efficient and depending on the routine size it may actually be slower than executing from flash (due to call overheads).  So, this would only be useful depending on **why** you need to put data in RAM (not TCRAM as per OP); for instance SMC.

Comment: Adding a `noinline` attribute might be useful as well, to ensure the code is not inlined into another function that *is* run from flash.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays (then-a-days as well?) you can just use the macro `__RAM_FUNC`, `__RAMFUNC_EXT(bank, name)` or `__RAMFUNC(bank)`

Comment: Non-standard C. Supported in IAR, not GCC.